# git push error in terminal(ubuntu)

Tags: git, github

On executing the code   : **git push origin master**
Following error comes.
  **Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts.
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**
```

Comment: as far as I understand, you're trying to push using public key? is it okay without key?

Comment: @pivanchy i am not using any key just these steps                                  git remote add origin https://github.com/sujeet14108/Calculator.git
git push -u origin master

Comment: could you try the next steps: `git clone <url_to_remote_repo>`, `git checkout master`, `git push origin master` ?

Comment: The issue has got nothing to do with linux. You have to add the keys to make it work.

Comment: @sandeep, I guess, it will be too difficult for the first time to understand how to work with keys. I propose to work without keys to have basic knowledge about how to work with git

Comment: Then add the remote for the `https://` address and not the `git@github` one. It will then just ask username and password every time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the public key on github(assuming) and not with ubuntu.

Have you added a ssh key on your account for github. Check whether the correct key is added(if you have multiple ones).
Have you tested you key connects to github using `ssh -T git@github.com`.
If you have not added ssh keys then generate a ssh key and add to gihub account. The instruction can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/)

Comment: yes, i have added ssh key on github account. But still showing same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ssh keys to connect to your server.

---

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)